# exchanging SSL certificates in MQ keystores

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

I am trying to make an SSL connection between two MQ servers. In both of them I am using self signed certificates, I created one cert for QM_A(sender) and another for QM_V(receiver). Since the connection will be 'one-way message' I am not sure if I have to extract the public key from QM_A and import it in the keystore of the QM_V(receiver)?

Right now in the error logs of QM_V I found the error message:

```
AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate.
```

Comment: What versions of MQ are on each queue manger?

Comment: Also provide the rest of the error from QM_V this will help confirm the exact cause.

Comment: both queue managers are 9.0.0.0 version and the complete error message from QM_V side is  AMQ9637: Channel is lacking a certificate.

EXPLANATION:
The channel is lacking a certificate to use for the SSL handshake. The channel
name is '????' (if '????' it is unknown at this stage in the SSL processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would want both queue mangers to have certs and to validate and match the DN of each other's cert.

---

The TLS server end (RCVR) must have a cert, while the TLS client end (SDR) optionally needs a cert depending on the `SSLCAUTH` setting of the RCVR.

In all cases if the SDR queue manger (TLS client) has a cert the RCVR queue manager (TLS server) will validate the SDR cert is signed by a trusted cert, not expired and optionally check it is not revoked by querying a CRL or OCSP server.  The RCVR queue manger will also check if the SDR cert's DN matches any SSLPEER values specified [and if at MQ v8.0 or later that the cert issuer matches any SSLCERTI values specified].

This is the behavior you would want to prevent unauthorized connections to the RCVR.

---

The SDR queue manager will also validate the RCVR queue manger cert is signed by a trusted cert, not expired and optionally check it is not revoked by querying a CRL or OCSP server.  You can also configure a single SSLPEER value on the SDR side that must match the RCVR queue manger's cert.  This will help to prevent a MITM attack.